# How to sum the result of a regex calculated field on Google Sheets with pivot table?

Tags: regex, google-sheets, pivot-table, google-sheets-formula, calculated-field

My MWE is very simple: I have a table that is

```
Company     Name    Insurance plan
A Inc.      A   
A Inc.      B       In_2020
A Inc.      C       In_2019
```

and I want to be able the count the number of employees of the company A Inc. that have an insurance plan using a pivot table.

To do this I use Calculated Field with the formula `=if(regexmatch(Insured, "(?i)In_"), 1, 0)"`, but when I set "Summarize by" to be "SUM" I get a #VALUE! error, and when I set it to Custom the total is just the result for the first employee (here, 0):

```
Company        Name     Calculated Field
A Inc.         A        0
               B        1
               C        1
A Inc. Total            0
```

Can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the help of someone offline, the answer is: `=COUNTIF(Insured,"*In_*")`

Answer (score 0):

you can do:

```
=COUNTA(IFNA(FILTER(B2:B5, REGEXMATCH(C2:C5, "^In_+"))))
```

[image: 0]

---

or use `QUERY` like:

```
=QUERY(A2:C, 
 "select A,count(A) 
  where C contains 'In_' 
  group by A 
  label count(A)''", 0)
```

[image: 0]

Comment: This does not work in a pivot table though, because you aggregate the results yourself while there is an aggregation part done by the pivot table that I don't get